# C++11 regular expressions and the string u8 prefix

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Though I've tested it myself for some time now, I am still not sure whether the following has any effect. Say I have a regex of the form

```
regex reg(R"(\s+)" + a + R"(\s+(.*?)\s+)" + b + R"(\s+)", regex_constants::icase);
```

where a and b are strings with some content

```
string a = u8"größer";
string b = u8"grüner";
```

that is strings with UTF-8 content (I took random examples, there could as well be some Arabic or whatever in there).

My question is whether the following has any effect on the result:

```
regex reg(u8R"(\s+)" + a + u8R"(\s+(.*?)\s+)" + b + u8R"(\s+)", regex_constants::icase);
```

I've in none of my tests noted a difference, the outcome was always the same with and without the u8 prefix. So, is this really useless or is there some hidden effect that I just haven't encountered yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only effect that the `u8` prefix has on string literals is that the literal shall be *guaranteed* to be encoded in UTF-8. An implementation is allowed to encode unprefixed literals as UTF-8, but that varies from implementation to implementation.

The `u8` prefix does not guarantee that your regex engine actually understands Unicode case folding, for example. Nor does it guarantee that it understands Unicode period; odds are good that it's treating matches based on a byte sequence, not based on Unicode rules.